# Trying to implement a rebalance method in binary search tree, having issues getting the middle of a lyst inside of a method

Tags: python

```
    def inorder(self):
        """ inorder """
        return self.inorder_helper(self.root)

    def inorder_helper(self, cur_node):
        """ inorder helper """
        RecursionCounter()
        lyst = []
        if cur_node is not None:
            lyst += self.inorder_helper(cur_node.left_child)
            lyst.append(str(cur_node.data))
            lyst += self.inorder_helper(cur_node.right_child)

        final_lyst = list(map(int, lyst))
        return final_lyst

    def rebalance_tree(self):
        newlyst = inorder(self)
        newroot = len(newlyst-1) / 2
        midderoot = newlyst[newroot]
        print(newroot)

bst = BinarySearchTree()

bst.add(5)
bst.add(10)
bst.add(12)
bst.add(20)
bst.rebalance_tree()
```

So i have this binary search tree, and i am trying to add a method to make it a AVL tree, and have a rebalance tree method.

So the first thing i need to do is take the middle value of the inorder lyst and make it into the root for the rebalance tree.

However, this is not working correctly. If you take a look at the code, i tried to get a newlyst and make it equal to the method inorder, which returns a list of inorder.

I then tried to take the length and divide it by 2, essentially getting the middle value, and then printing it.

However i am getting a "inorder" is not defined error. how do i get the lyst from inorder inside of rebalance_tree? I need the rebalance tree to also have no parameters, but i could have helper functions.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to fix your indentation. Your code currently does not make sense.

Comment: I apologize, all three of these methods are inside of a binary search tree class. @khelwood i fixed the indentation.

Comment: `inorder` *isn't* defined in the current scope or in any enclosing scope; you need to call it as `self.inorder()`.